# Bitmovin player on Safari does not load captions selection options from media SourceConfig

Tags: angular, safari, bitmovin-player

I'm using the Bitmovin player (v8.15) in an Angular App. I've configured the player as follows and defined the callback

```
this._player = new Player(this.videoPlayer.nativeElement, {
  ...bitmovinConfig,
  events: {
    // other code removed

    [SubtitleAdded]: () => this.triggerCaptionChange(),

    // other code removed
  },
});

triggerCaptionChange() {
  const captions = this._player.subtitles.list() as MediaCaption[];
  console.log(captions);
  // other code removed
}
```

MediaCaption in Chrome looks like this (we basically extend bitmovin's SubtitleTrack interface and added `subType` and `sideloaded`:

```
"id": "1",
"url": "https://...myurl_hidden.../DASH/5b95ba67-75bc-4127-bcaa-182a819f649c_WebVTT_eng.vtt",
"kind": "caption",
"lang": "en-US",
"subType": "subtitles",
"sideloaded": true,
"label": "English",
"enabled": true
```

We are also loading the player with a config as follows:

```
async onSourceChange(_: SourceConfig, current: SourceConfig) {  
  await this._player.load(current); 
  this.triggerAudioChange();
  this.triggerCaptionChange(); 

  ...
}
```

In Chrome `current` looks like this:

```
"hls": "https://...urlhidden.../spmx/.../.../Dash/DASH_pertitle-dash.mpd",
"dash": "https://...urlhidden.../spmx/.../...Dash/DASH_pertitle-dash.mpd",
"drm": hidden,

"subtitleTracks": [
    {
      "enabled": "false",
      "id": "1",
      "url": "https://...urlhidden.../spmx/.../.../Dash/Subtitles_es_419.vtt",
      "kind": "caption",
      "label": "es-419",
      "lang": "es-419",
      "subType": "Subtitles",
      "sideloaded": true
    },
    {
      "enabled": "false",
      "id": "3",
      "url": "https://...urlhidden.../spmx/.../.../Dash/Captions_en_US.vtt",
      "kind": "caption",
      "label": "es-US",
      "lang": "en-US",
      "subType": "Captions",
      "sideloaded": true
    }
  ],
  "options": {
    "startTime": 1709
  }
```

In Safari `current` looks like this (note, no `dash` key):

```
"hls": "https://...urlhidden.../spmx/.../.../Apple/HLS_main.m3u8",
"drm": hidden,
"subtitleTracks": [
    {
      "enabled": "false",
      "id": "1",
      "url": "https://...urlhidden.../spmx/.../.../Apple/Subtitles_es-419.m3u8",
      "kind": "caption",
      "lang": "es-419",
      "lang": "es-419",
      "subType": "SUBTITLES",
      "sideloaded": true
    },
    {
      "enabled": "false",
      "id": "2",
      "url": "https://...urlhidden.../spmx/.../.../Apple/Subtitles_es_419.vtt",
      "kind": "caption",
      "lang": "es-419",
      "lang": "es-419",
      "subType": "Subtitles",
      "sideloaded": true
    },
    {
      "enabled": "false",
      "id": "4",
      "url": "https://...urlhidden.../spmx/.../.../Apple/Captions_en-US.m3u8",
      "kind": "caption",
      "lang": "en-US",
      "lang": "en-US",
      "subType": "SUBTITLES",
      "sideloaded": true
    }
    {
      "enabled": "false",
      "id": "5",
      "url": "https://...urlhidden.../spmx/.../.../Apple/Captions_en_US.vtt",
      "kind": "caption",
      "lang": "en-US",
      "lang": "en-US",
      "subType": "Captions",
      "sideloaded": true
    }
  ],
  "options": {
    "startTime": 1709
  }
```

In Chrome: the console log gives me an array with two items.

In Safari: I get an empty array.

Comment: what player version are you using? What is the format of the subtitle files? And the source manifest file?

Comment: I created a sample app here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/bitmovin-player-angular-app?file=src%2Fapp%2Fvideo-player%2Fvideo-player.component.ts but couldn't reproduce the issue. After adding the player key, in both Chrome and Safari the console shows 3 elements. What is `MediaCaption`? Have you tried clearing out the cache and reloading the page in Safari?

Comment: Hi Andrea:  I've added some details to the post above.  We are using player v.8.15, for chrome we are providing a DASH manifest file and for Safari a HLS file.

Comment: When I go to the .vtt subtitle/caption links I see the contents of a WEBVTT file...but if I go to the .m3u8 files I get 403.  Is that the cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to contact Bitmovin and after some discussions with them I had to load the SubtitleNative module (bitmovinplayer-subtitles-native). Make sure you load it after the Subtitles module (bitmovinplayer-subtitles)

```
import BitmovinSubtitlesNativeModule from 'bitmovin-player/modules/bitmovinplayer-subtitles-native';
Player.addModule(BitmovinSubtitlesNativeModule);
```

When I did this, my sideloaded entries were loaded by bitmovin'.  However, on Safari my custom 'subType' and 'sidedloaded' fields that I added to the subtitleTracks[] are stripped.  (We use those to help us distinguish which tracks were sideloaded and which were loaded by the player from the manifest.

We decided to encode our subType and sidedloaded values into the `label` field of subtitleTracks. Now we're able to display these sideloaded caption options in our custom player UI.

Now the Bitmovin player calls my onCueEnter/Exit callbacks for me to render the caption text!

Comment: What do you mean by
>  it didn't not recognize the 'subType' and 'sidedloaded' fields that I added
? What do you expect the player to do with custom fields?